# How to convert ssh command 'df -h' result in json format?

Tags: php, ssh, phpseclib, diskspace

I am using phpseclib SSH2 to connect ec2 server. I want to get disk space details in json format. I run the command as below:

```
$command = "df -h"; 
echo $ssh->exec($command);
```

Output is:

```
Filesystem Size Used Avail Use% Mounted on devtmpfs 475M 0 475M 0% /dev tmpfs 483M 0 483M 0% /dev/shm tmpfs 483M 552K 483M 1% /run tmpfs 483M 0 483M 0% /sys/fs/cgroup /dev/xvda1 30G 2.5G 28G 9% / fs-035d9649ed9793406.efs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:/ 8.0E 0 8.0E 0%  /var/www/html/efsmount/Customer1 /dev/mapper/customervolumegroup-Cus2 5.0G 38M 5.0G 1% /var/www/html/efsmount/Cus2 /dev/mapper/customervolumegroup-Cus3 5.0G 38M 5.0G 1% /var/www/html/efsmount/Cus3 /dev/mapper/customervolumegroup-Cus4 5.0G 38M 5.0G 1% /var/www/html/efsmount/Cus4 tmpfs 97M 0 97M 0% /run/user/1000
```

The result is in string format. How to convert this to json format?

Comment: You would need to parse the data you want out from that string, add it to an array with the format you want and encode it into json. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

I convert the above output into array first.

```
        $command = "df -h"; 
        $s= $ssh->exec($command);
        $data = trim($s);

        $data = array_map(function($line){
            $elements=preg_split('/\s+/',$line);
            return(array(
            'filesystem' => $elements[0],
            'size' => $elements[1],
            'used' => $elements[2],
            'available' => $elements[3],
            'use%' => $elements[4],
            ));
    },explode("\n",$data));
```

Then encode this into json.